# Automating Client Side Performance Testing

Tags: performance, google-chrome, client, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I am analyzing the client-side performance of a particular website using the Performance tab in chrome dev tools. It is a manual process.is there a tool that could automate this process and generate the report once the test is over?

Answer (score 0):

You need a browser automation framework like or [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) so you could kick off a browser instance, visit page(s), click buttons, etc.

The performance metrics can be queries by calling [User Timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User_Timing_API) and [Navigation Timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) APIs functions, JavaScript can be invoked via [executeScript() function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) which will return either [Window.Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance) object or set your custom timestamps.

If you're new to the whole browser automation concept see [Selenium WebDriver for Beginners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selenium-webdriver-for-beginners) article